Node module Printer was compiled against a different Node.js version
I am trying to Update my angular project which is from angular version 8 to 9. I have used electron in my angular project. Currently I am updating my angular version 4.0.0 to 7.1.7 and in that process I am encountered with this error. I am using node-printer module version 0.4.0
node_modules\printer\lib\node_printer.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).


I have tried following solutions found on various sources

Remove node_modules and re-install after clearing cache.
Rebuild project with npm rebuild
My current node version is 12.8.4 and I have tried re-installation of node_modules with node versions 12.22.x, 12.8.1, 14.21.3 but none of this worked
When tried to do npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
got this error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"^4.0.0","tsd-check'

